# How to determine macro value at compilation time in C?

Tags: c, compilation, macros, cc

If I have a macro in my C:

```
#ifdef SIGDET
#if SIGDET == 1
    isSignal = 1;       /*Termination detected by signals*/
#endif
#endif
```

How can I set the value at compilation time? Is it some parameter to the compiler?

Comment: Are there actually other values it can have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C compilers allow macros to be defined on the command line, usually with the `-D` command line option:

This defines the macro `SIGDET` to the value `1`.

```
gcc -DSIGDET myprogram.c
```

You can specify the value this way:

```
gcc -DSIGDET=42 myprogram.c
```

You can even define the macro as empty:

```
gcc -DSIGDET=  myprogram.c
```

Given how your program is written, defining SIGDET as empty would cause a compilation error.  Defining `SIGDET` to `2` would have the same effect as not defining `SIGDET` at all, this might not be what you expect.

It might be preferable to consider any numeric definition of `SIGDET` different than `0` to trigger the conditional code.  You could then use these tests:

```
#ifdef SIGDET
#if SIGDET+0
    isSignal = 1;       /*Termination detected by signals*/
#endif
#endif
```

Or this alternative:

```
#if defined(SIGDET) && SIGDET+0
    isSignal = 1;       /*Termination detected by signals*/
#endif
```